# iOS - How to set textfield hint to italic (with regular actual text)?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

Is there any easy way to set a text field's hint to italic, while keeping the actual text non-italicized? The image below shows what I'm trying to accomplish, but doesn't actually work, as text typed into the first text field is still italicized.

[image: text fields]

If there's no easy way to do this, I'm thinking that I'll have to implement methods on each of the text fields to check the length of the text, and if zero apply the italic font. This would work, right? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIFont* italicFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];    
[yourTextField setValue:italicFont forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.font"];
```

---

EDIT:

Ok, here is another (legal) way to do it:

- 1.Subclass `UITextField` and override `drawPlaceholderInRect:`:

TextFieldSubclass.h:

```
@interface TextFieldSubclass : UITextField

@end
```

TextFieldSubclass.m:

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    [[UIColor lightGrayColor] setFill];
    UIFont* italicFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:italicFont];
}
```

- 2.Change your `UITextField` class and set it to TextFieldSubclass:

[image]

And that's it. Enjoy.

Comment: This may work, however it is accessing private instance variables, and as such, Apple may reject the application from the App Store...

Comment: I know of something similar passing the review, so I think this code is fine.