# UITextField hints on iPhone using C#

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, xamarin

I'd like to place temporary text in the `UITextField` on my iPhone app.  Android has the hint property to display temporary text in the textfield.  How do I do the same in iPhone development?

Comment: Temporary text means place holder?

Comment: Yes, how do I put placeholder text into a UITexField in C#?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11479680/1328096

Comment: if you are thinking of pop-up or flyover a text field, that's not a supported in ios.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UITextFields have a Placeholder property that let you set the hint text:

```
MyTextField.Placeholder = "Required";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches to used  place holder for UITextfield some good way given below

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 29);
UITextField *search= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
search.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
search.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
search.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
search.placeholder = @"Suchen";
search.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
search.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
search.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
search.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
search.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
search.delegate = self;
```

1. [link 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_text_field.htm)
2. [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1998090/1328096)
3. [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479680/1328096)

I hope it helps you.Thanks